# Matrix inconsistent & dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've understood a system to be

Dependent if at least one row is
$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$

Inconsistent if atleast one row is
$ 
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
0 & 0 & 0 & b \\
\end{array}, b\in\mathbb{Z}\neq0$

In the matrix below, I've used Gauss elimination and found out that if a=2 it's inconsistent and if a=1 it's dependent. But I believe that there are more solutions to a that makes it either dependent or inconsistent. How do I find out all solutions if I have an unknown variable in the matrix? Is it just by trial and error through Gauss elim?

$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2 & 3 & a & 5 \\
1 & 2 & a & 3 \\
3 & a & -2 & 4  \\
\end{array}
$

Comment: The determinat is $$-(a-2) (a-1)$$ and the RREF is $$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{2 (a-1)}{a-2} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -\dfrac{2}{a-2} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{a-2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ Your conclusions are correct, but the above should resolve your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Gauß' elimination* leads to (without any hypothesis on the values of $a$):
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&a&|&3\\
0&1&a&|&1\\
0&0&(1-a)(a-2)&|&1-a
\end{bmatrix}$$
This is enough to conclude, without any trial and errors.

Comment: I've got no problem finding out your R1 & R2 but where did you get R3 from?  Big ups, by the way!

Comment: There's a moment when the last two rows are $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&a&1\\0&a-6&-2-3a&-5\end{bmatrix}$$ if I'm not mistaken. Initially, I swapped rows 1and 2.

Comment: Yes. Both of them I've been able to find. I'll have to take a while to think about it because I don't see how they relate to R3

Comment: I simply replaced $R_3$ with $r_3-(a-6)r_2$ and factored out the third coefficient of the new  last row.

Comment: I get it now! It hadn't even crossed my mind that I could use variables in the coefficient of row addition

Comment: Provided it's not the coefficient of the row you're acting on.